# Changing the colours of specific words in tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tumblr

In tumblr, and in a post, what is the relevant code I need to know to change the colour of the title and specific words?

I'm very new, and do not know the right terminologies. Please link to the relevant guides and resources.

Please move this question to another site if it's better.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you be specific about the items you want to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see those tutorials :

1.[blog_customization](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/blog_customization)

2.[basic-codes](http://academyoftumblr.tumblr.com/post/4631709588/basic-codes)

3.[See this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEvRxhl4lRk)

And if you need more info, google is then best way to find everything :)

**EDIT**

To change the colors of specific words you could use :

```
<font color="htmlcolor">text</font>
```

If you want to change the background you can use :

```
<div style="width:190px; height:12px; background-color:#000000; text-align:left; color: #ffffff;">text</div>
```

To edit your blog in Tumblr you have to do :

***How do I edit my blog’s Custom HTML?***

1. Click "Settings" under the Account menu at the top of the Dashboard.
2. Choose the blog you’d like to update on the right side of the page,
   then click “Edit theme” in the Website Theme section.
3. Click the Edit HTML button and edit the Custom HTML as desired in
   the source code editor to see the changes reflected on the page
4. Click “Update Preview.”
5. When you're finished, click the back arrow and then click "Save."

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but link based answers are generally frowned up. If the linked content is removed, the answer holds no relevance.

Comment: @mikedidthis Duh, my bad sorry, so shall to explain a little bit what does the url contain?

Comment: @Skizo If the OP clarifies what they want to change, adding the code relating to them items would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Just as Skizo said,

To change the colors of particular words you can use

```
<span class="color">text</span>
```

And then set the color of the class color to pink. Using a class is better if you want to change the color of multiple words in different areas of your code to the same color.

And for background color you can use something like this

```
<h1 style="background-color:#123432">text</h1>
```